# Few questions about realization of commands using bash scripts

Tags: bash, scripting

I need to create bash script file, which after its launch does following.

1) Suppose after launching the script I enter the text 'abc'. Then the script must automatically generate commands

```
cat text.txt
echo '123' > text.txt
echo 'abc' >>text.txt
echo '456' >>text.txt
```

2) After doing that I need to execute some commands (like compile the program etc.).

How to create bash script which executes these tasks?

Comment: You'll probably want to look at manual the `bash` builtin `read`  and the `-n` flag for echo.    But take a look at `sed` and rethink your concept as loading your phrase into a variable, say `$NEW`, and then running `sed 's/123456/123'"$NEW"'456'`  Which probably has it own issues, especially if `$NEW` gets a slash inside it,  but its a first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the top and bottom are fixed, it can be something like:

```
cat top.txt /dev/stdin bottom.txt > text.txt 
# with cat, - works the same as /dev/stdin
```

or

```
{ 
  echo 123 #top.txt
  cat
  echo 456 #bottom.txt
} > text.txt
```

followed by your compilation commands

```
cat top.txt /dev/stdin bottom.txt > text.txt
gcc whatever
```

The first line should be a shebang line specifying your interpreter, unless you're OK with `/bin/sh`

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cat top.txt /dev/stdin bottom.txt > text.txt
 gcc whatever
```

If you then mark the script executable with `chmod +x the_script`,
`./the_script` will be equivalent to `/bin/bash ./the_script`.

If you want the scrip to abort a command fails, start it with `set -e` (or make the shebang line (`#!/bin/bash -e`).

**Edit:**

`cat` expects a whole file (until you enter ctr-d -- the end of file marker). If you want just one line, you can do read -r something; printf '%s\n' "$something" or `head -n1`.

You can read the help  pages of the commands with `man $command` or `help $command`.

Comment: Thank You very much! But when I launch 'cat top.txt /dev/stdin bottom.txt > text.txt', it doesn't execute (i.e, it enters the input mode, I enter something and write "Enter", but it doesn't going out the input mode). What is the problem?

Comment: Oh, `cat` expects a whole file (until you enter ctr-d -- the end of file marker). If you want just one line, you can do `read -r something; printf '%s\n' "$something"` or `head -n1`.

Comment: Thank You one more! And, if You please, may I ask You about details of Your answer, if I'll stuck?